# What version of SQL must be installed in another system

Tags: c#, database, windows, sql-server-2008-r2

I create database with SQL Server 2008 R2.
Now, I want execute database with C# windows Application in Other system.
What version of SQL must be installed in another system?

Comment: Must be `SQL Server 2008 R2` or greater then `SQL Server 2008 R2`

Comment: Why? SQL Server 2008 r2 is very high for a low hardware.

Comment: Thank you very much [link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1776785/khurram-ali).